# TortoiseSVN Credentials

Tags: ssh, cygwin, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN cannot access credentials from under cygwin-sshd, unless I'm also logged in via Remote Desktop.

Environment: Win2019 Server with TortoiseSVN and Cygwin. svn server is on the corporate VPN, it's not a local install.  (Also I'm fairly sure it's configured for svn-ssh access.)

I usually access it via ssh to cygwin's sshd. I'll use Remote Desktop when I have to, but prefer ssh.

- Log in via ssh, but no RD session: svn will prompt for credentials.
- Log in to Remote Desktop, then log in via ssh ... now svn can use cached credentials.

Apparently TortoiseSVN can't access it's credentials-cache unless a Windows UI is loaded. Is there a way around this?